# Program to print a half-hollow shape

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where I have to print out a shape like this:

> Let number of rows =9, and char a=x, char b=y and char c=z
>   [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci1bL.png)

Anyway, I havent been able to accomplish much.
I managed to print two half triangles w/ one of them inverted, but, the output has this [weird line breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehskC.png). I also cant seem to know how I'm supposed to alternate the letters each time. 
Here's what I managed to do so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void PrintFigure(int n, char a, char b, char c)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int m=n/2;

// for upper half-triangle

        for(i=0;i<=(n/2);i++)
    {
       for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
       {
    cout<<" ";
       }
       for(k=m-i-1;k>=0;k--)
       {
   cout<<a;
       }
       cout<<endl;
    }

// for the middle line

    for (i=0; i<=m ;i++)
    {
        if (i%2==0) cout<< b; else cout <<c;
    }

// for the lower half-triangle

    for (i=n;i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(j=1;j<i;j++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (k=m;k>=i;k--)
        {
            cout <<c;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Figure1 starts:"<<endl;
    PrintFigure(9, 'x', 'y', 'z');
    cout<<"Figure1 ends:"<<endl;

    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Figure2 starts:"<<endl;
    PrintFigure(15, '*', '-', '+');
    cout<<"Figure2 ends:"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: 1) Please reformat your code. 2) First design an algorithm to perform a specific task, than write code.

Answer (score 0):

The output is not doing "weird line breaks", it is just doing what you have defined.

Yor first Loop is running from i=0 till i<=(n/2), this means it runs five times, for i=0 till i=4.
Change

```
i<=(n/2)
```

to

```
i<(n/2)
```

Also you defined your for-loop for the second half-triangle to n, n is 9 lines in your first output, so it is giving you 9 lines in your output.

change

```
// for the lower half-triangle
for (i=n;i>=1;i--)
```

to

```
cout << endl;
// for the lower half-triangle
for (i=n/2;i>=1;i--)
```

As a hint for alternating letters, if your variable char a = 'x', you can print the next letter (y) with:

```
cout << (++a);
```

As example:

```
char a = 'w';
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    cout << (++a);
```

Output:

```
xyz
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 0):

See the below Code i slightly changed your code for you expected output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void PrintFigure(int n, char a, char b, char c)
{
    int m=n/2;

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j>0;j--)
             cout<<" ";
        for(int j=m-i,p=1;j>0;j--,p++)
             cout<< ( (p==1) ? a :( (p==2) ? b:(p=0,c) ) );

        cout<<endl;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
             cout<<((i%2==0)?b:c);

    for(int i=m;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for(int j=i;j>0;j--)
             cout<<" ";
        for(int j=m-i,p=1;j>0;j--,p++)
             cout<< ( (p==1) ? a :( (p==2) ? b:(p=0,c) ) );

        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Figure1 starts:"<<endl;
    PrintFigure(9, 'x', 'y', 'z');
    cout<<"Figure1 ends:"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is

```
( (p==1) ? a :( (p==2) ? b:(p=0,c) ) )
```

equal to

```
if(p==1)
   cout<<a;
else if(p==2)
   cout<<b;
else if(p==3)
{
  cout<<c;
  p=0;
}
```

Output:

```
Figure1 starts:
xyzx
 xyz
  xy
   x
yzyz
   x
  xy
 xyz
xyzx
Figure1 ends:

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.047 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: @Farah Ahmed   you are welcome and feel free to accept any one of the answer , if you got it.